# How to traverse a N ary tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, nodes, traversal

I have some working code with the help of others which creates a 3 deep N ary tree (or just 3 linked nodes), but I don't know how to traverse the list of nodes to find data - for example the trip distance for CarNo=6, Driver=Thor4 and TripNo=38. Sorry if this is trivial, I'm new to data structures and [extensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795799/how-to-traverse-a-n-ary-tree) net searches hasn't helped. Thanks for any help.

```
public class Node
        {
            public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
            public Node Parent = null;
            public Node(Node fromParent = null)
            {
                if (fromParent != null)
                {
                    Parent = fromParent;
                    fromParent.Children.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }

        public class Root : Node
        {
            public int PoolNo;
            public int CarNo;
            string Make;

            public Root(int _PoolNo, int _CarNo, string _Make) : base(null)
            {
                PoolNo = _PoolNo;
                CarNo = _CarNo;
                Make = _Make;
            }
        }

        public class Parameter : Node
        {
            public string Driver;
            public Parameter(string _Driver, Node fromParent = null) : base(fromParent)
            {
                Driver = _Driver;
            }
        }

        public class Value : Node
        {
            public int TripDistance;
            public int TripNo;
            public Value(int _TripDistance, int _TripNo, Node fromParent = null) : base(fromParent)
            {
                TripDistance = _TripDistance;
                TripNo = _TripNo;
            }
        }


        List<Node> CarPool = new List<Node>();
        public void IDTree()
        {

            Random Rnd = new Random();
            for (int K = 1; K <= 20; K++)
            {
                var Car = new Root(6,K, "Ford" + K);                 // PoolNo,CarNo,Make          
                for (int KK = 1; KK <= 30; KK++)
                {
                    var Driver = new Parameter("Thor" + KK, Car);       // Driver                   
                    for (int KKK = 1; KKK <= 58; KKK++)
                    {
                        int Distance = Rnd.Next(1, 1000);
                        var Details = new Value(Distance, KKK, Driver);    // TripDistance,TripNo        
                    }
                }
                CarPool.Add(Car);
            }

            // traverse CarPool list to find trip distance for Carno 6, driver Thor4, tripno 38
            foreach(var T in CarPool)
            {
                // not sure how to do this...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm understanding this wrong, but it doesn't look like you need to traverse the tree, but rather reference a particular node on the tree. In that case, what's wrong with something like `CarPool[6].Children[4].Children[38].TripDistance`?

Comment: You're right -  that's what I'm looking for, but ``TripDistance`` doesn't compile. I don't know if you need to traverse the nodes or just use a simple lookup like you showed.

Comment: It's my bad. I neglected to take into account that the objects in Children are of type `Node`, so they need to be cast into `Value` before TripDistance will be accessible. `(CarPool[6].Children[4].Children[38] as Value).TripDistance`.

Comment: that works, thanks. But I really need the Driver to be a string like ``"Thor4"`` instead of an integer ``4``. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<string, Node>` instead of a List and use the Node's name (car's Make, driver's Driver, etc.) as the key. (You would need to come up with a string value for your `Value` nodes to use as a key.)

Comment: That's a good idea since the ``Make`` and ``Driver`` won't change. I'm not sure how to do this can you post some code?

Comment: All you need to do is replace `List<Node>` with `Dictionary<string, Node>` and change any `Children.Add(someNode)` with `Children.Add(keyName, someNode)`.

Comment: But depending on the depth of the node sometimes the key will be an integer, like ``CarNo``, and sometimes a string, like ``Driver``. That's why I thought I had to traverse each node and check what its values were and then drop down into its children.

Comment: Is this a requirement of the program? Because IMO you shouldn't be designing a data structure that requires you to potentially traverse the entire structure in order to locate a single node, as that causes look-up times to be O(n) as opposed to a List's or Dictionary's O(1). Using a single type (either `string` or `int`) lets you take advantage of inheritance and keeps the design of your structure fast and simple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123783/discussion-between-zeus-and-abion47).